# Passing a Value from Objective-C to Phonegap

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova, dom-events

I am using phonegap to create an application and I need to check if a document exists and read off the document if it does exist and pass the value to phonegap. I would also like to make the initial screen in Objective-C and on button press go onto the phonegap version. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question - you could use the File object that PhoneGap/Cordova provides. If it does not do exactly what you want then you can write your own plugin.

To answer your second question - you can use the PhoneGap/Cordova WebView as a component on iOS. Read this link for details - https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/How%20to%20Use%20Cordova%20as%20a%20Component.md

Comment: Cordova is the new name for PhoneGap